# API get value Tumblr

Tags: php, api, tumblr

I'm trying to use Tumblrs API and when I visit the URL for the API I get this below

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": 200
        "msg": "OK",
    },
    "response": {
        "blog": {
            "title": "Ex-Sample",
            "posts": 20,
            "name": "example",
            "url": "http://example.tumblr.com/",
            "updated": 1327794725,
            "description": "A sample document used to provide examples of the various [and <i>varying</i>] HTML tags Tumblr puts out. Quote, specifically, has a lot of variants.",
            "ask": false
        }
    }
}
```

The URL is http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/example.tumblr.com/info?api_key=(APIKEY)

I'm trying to get what the "post" number is with that URL above. How would I do that in PHP and echo the number only out?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a JSON string, so...

```
$msg = '{"meta" etc.....';
$data = json_decode($msg);
echo $data['meta']['response']['blog']['posts'];
```

You can use

```
var_dump($data);
```

to dump the entire response in a nicely formatted tree structure.

Comment: Easy enough my questions is how will I put the url into the $msg var here is the url http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/example.tumblr.com/info?api_key=YXOMnkQFQ4de5PXkEcwQTtN2a54KxJkECt2KEKQhIaMdi0AVK5

Comment: You how would you actually FETCH that data? `file_get_contents($url)` is the easiest, but if that's not available, there's cURL and a few other options as well.

Comment: How would you use file_get_contents($url) can you show me a example.